# importing existing project into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I run in to alot of errors when i want to import and existing android project on to my eclipse on my laptop. i tried several solutions but keep getting these errors. I hope someone can help me

http://i57.tinypic.com/w171n4.png

Thanks in advance!

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /WowQuiz/res/values line 9  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml  /WowQuiz/res/values-v11 line 9  Android AAPT Problem
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java   /WowQuiz/src/com/example/wowquiz    line 165    Java Problem
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type InfoScreen   InfoScreen.java /WowQuiz/src/com/example/wowquiz    line 34 Java Problem
```

Comment: Importing android project in ecllipse is a real pain. There are android studio project library for which you need to provide src directories. Also the library may be old and contain other library or jar reference. There is no silver bullet for this problem.

Comment: delete your bin and gen folders and clean and re build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno whether this is the problem,, have u put the support v7 library in the project 
D:\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs
As far as i know the appcompat comes with v7 library..just add the library and add to build path and try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you import ActionBarAppCompat Library to your Workspace  and then add it to the main Project.

Select Project---> Right Click --> Properties  --> Select Android on the Left Side Pane---> Go to down on the right side --> Click Add ---> now Select Appcompat Library and click ok

Answer (score 0):

This may help (using Eclipse Mars 4.5):

```
* File > Import...
* General > Existing Projects into Workspace > Next
* Select root directory (and browse to project)
* Untick Copy projects into workspace
* Untick Add project to working sets
* Finish
```